# Filter - Error Rendering View[/Error.xhtml] java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: jsf, redirect, nullpointerexception, prerenderview

I've the following context:

a xhtml page, like this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>My Event</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</h:head>

<body>
    <f:event listener="#{filterEventCreator.check}" type="preRenderView" />
    ...
```

This is the filterEventCreator:

```
public void check(ComponentSystemEvent event) {
    if(amIComingFromDispatcher()){
        SYSO_Testing.syso("FilterEventCreator in this case, everything it's ok");
        sessionUtility.setNotComingFromDispatcher();
    }
    else{
        try {
            SYSO_Testing.syso("I'm not coming from redirect");
            sessionUtility.sessionLogout();
            response.sendRedirect(errorPath);
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FilterEventCreator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
}
private boolean amIComingFromDispatcher() {
    if(this.loggedUser==null)return false;
    return sessionUtility.getComingFromDispatcher();
}
```

Where the sessionUtility is the following one:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class SessionUtility implements Serializable {

private String loggedUserName, loggedUserPassword;
private int errorCode, eventID;
private boolean error, comingFromDispatcher;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    error = false;
    comingFromDispatcher = false;
}

public void addUser(String username) {
    loggedUserName = username;
    SYSO_Testing.syso("User added in cache");
}

public String getLoggedUser() {
    return loggedUserName;
}

public void sessionLogout() {
    SYSO_Testing.syso("starting logout from Session bean");
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
    loggedUserName = null;
    error = false;
    request.getSession().invalidate();

}

public void setError(int value) {
    errorCode = value;
    error = true;
}

public boolean isAnError() {
    return error;
}

public int getError() {
    return errorCode;
}

public void showedError() {
    error = false;
}


public void setNotComingFromDispatcher() {
    comingFromDispatcher = false;
}

public void setComingFromDispatcher() {
    comingFromDispatcher = true;
}

public boolean getComingFromDispatcher() {
    return comingFromDispatcher;
}
```

What's happen is that if I connect directly to the xhtml page, the filter understand that i'm neither logged and neither coming with a redirect but when it tries to redirect the following error arises:
 **Error Rendering View[/Error.xhtml] java.lang.NullPointerException**

I debug this project and neither the response nor any variable except for the loggedUser are null. I'm grateful to anyone that can help me.

Comment: This question is confusing. Where's the filter? What exactly is being `null` (and thus causing the NPE)?

Comment: I'm really grateful for your help, I try to explain better the situation:

the xhtml page has the <f:event listener="#{filterEventCreator.check}" type="preRenderView" /> 

that is invoked since the page is requested.
Once it's called without a login the check method goes until this print:
SYSO_Testing.syso("I'm not coming from redirect");
make the logout for a sessionBean that is the variable sessionUtility that is injected in the filter. When the method should do the redirect it doesn't load the Error.xhtml page but it open an error java page, with the error NPE.

Comment: FATAL:   JSF1073: java.lang.IllegalStateException caught during processing of RENDER_RESPONSE 6 : UIComponent-ClientId=, Message=Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
FATAL:   Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed

This is the error that really occurs, the NPE I notice only now that is not the first error is only the showed one.

Comment: I think that I understand the problem, in the logout I reset the request and the response. So what I could do is pass these as parameters from the filters in order to not lose the response. Do you agree with me?
Thanks for your advices !!!